# KVM: how do I add host route when VM starts?

Tags: networking, kvm, route

Is there a way to automatically add a host route (pointing to the VM IP) when VM starts ? ATM I'm doing this by hand. I've also tried to add a route via `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-virbr0` file, but it doesn't work, probably due to the fact that I don't have the appropriate `ifcfg-virbr0` file.

Adding just a static route pointing to the VM doesn't work for obvious reason - there's no appropriate network interface (`virbr0`) when the host enters the multiuser mode, so route addition just fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using libvirt, you can add [static routes](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsStaticroute) in the libvirt network XML.

For example:

```
  <route address="192.168.222.0" prefix="24" gateway="192.168.122.2"/>

  <route family="ipv6" address="2001:db8:ca2:3::" prefix="64" gateway="2001:db8:ca2:2::2"/>
```

Now libvirt will bring up the routes when it activates the virtual network.